# Exception thrown in onEnter - Not caught by main loop

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
try 
{
    Application.Run(myForm);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
   // handle
}
```

In my `MyForm`, when I throw an exception in a button click handler, it is caught as expected and handled by the above code. When I throw in the form's `onEnter` handler, it is not caught.

Comment: If you add a handler to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` does it get caught there?

Comment: It does, but I want it in my main loop, because there I can completely terminate my application. If it is caught in a different handler, I have to jump through hoops to terminate. Most notably, there are some `onClose` handlers that can also throw an exception I try to handle here, leading to multiple error message, while it is in fact just one (to be precise, I want to handle connection lost on a database).

Answer (score 1):

Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

```
   public static void Main()
   {
      AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
      currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

     Application.Run(myForm);
   }

   static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
   {
      Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
      Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
      Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating);
   }
```